# VS2017 msbuild / nuget pack

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am having a problem with nuget (version 4.3.0.4406) and msbuild (version 15.3.409.57025). I am using VS2017 to create class library. Using the **pack** capability of VS2017 i can successfully create a nuget package (that i can install in another solution). Now i want to add an install.ps1 script to the package in the tools folder that runs when the nuget is installed.

In the csproj file i am specifying multiple target frameworks:

`<TargetFrameworks>net45;net452</TargetFrameworks>`

I cannot figure out how to do this. I've created a nuspec file using the nuget -spec command which generates a simple nuspec file. When i use the msbuild command with the /t:pack and /p:Nuspecfile=path.to.nuspec I get the following errors:

NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(141,5): error : Value cannot be null or an empty string.

I have nuspec files from other projects (from VS2015 solutions) that work without problem, and the structure of the one i am using now is basically the same. Can anyone let me know whether i am trying something that cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can pack any item by updating its metadata in the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="install.ps1" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Pack="true" PackagePath="\tools" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that the ps1 file is only run for projects using `packages.config` to reference the NuGet package and you should investigate alternative ways to accomplish what you are trying to do with the script as `PackageReference` is now more likely to be used instead.

Comment: thanks for that, i will give it a try later today and report back if it worked. The project that consumes the package is a WPF project using packages.config. So, that should be fine then.

Comment: Yes, unless a future VS version attempts to migrate the projects (but it should keep project file modifications). new projects could use the new way of referencing packages.

Comment: I have tried Martin's suggestion. It only seems to work when i specify one target framework using the <TargetFramework> element in the csproj file. When I use the <TargetFrameworks> element (only specifying for instance net452) it does not include a tools folder in the resulting nuget package :-( Does anyone have a solution for this specific case?